# Fatal Error: Failed to load JIT Compiler issue | Attempting to move files from SQL db to Azure Storage

Tags: c#, sql-server, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022, windows-11

I am running into a system "System.OutOfMemoryException" in my VS 2022 console application .net core 6.0.

Here is the error:

```
error: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadPlpBytes(Byte[]& buff, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalBytesRead)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, Boolean readHeaderOnly)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at FileToAzureTransfer.AzureFileTransferMain.GetFileData
```

I figured this might be caused due to the application running in 32 bit.

I Released to 64 bit and I verified that the CPU is 64 bit.

[image]

Now when I try to run the .exe, I see this error:

***Fatal Error: Failed to Load JIT Compiler?***

I cannot find anything on the web to point me to why the JIT Compiler is not loading?

I'm using Windows 11/VS 2022

Here is the code to get my blob data:

```
        private static async Task<byte[]> GetFileData(int fileSystemId)
        {
            try
            {
                var sqlQueryToGetFile = $@"SELECT [FileData]
                             FROM [dbo].[FileSystem] WHERE [FileSystemId] = @FileId";

                using (var newConnection = new SqlConnection(FileShareConnectionString))
                {
                    using (var newCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryToGetFile, newConnection))
                    {
                        newCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                        newCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileId", fileSystemId);

                        await newConnection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                        using (var reader = await newCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                        {
                            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                            {
                                return (byte[])reader["FileData"];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return new byte[0];
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter($"Error_GetFileData_{filePathPostText}.txt", true))
                {
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync($"error info: {errorInfo}");
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(" --- ");
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync($"error: {ex.ToString()}");
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(" --- ");
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync($"sbInfo: ");
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(sbInfo.ToString());
                    await writer.WriteLineAsync(" ------------------------------------------------------ ");
                }

                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Aside: except for the exception (ASP.NET Core), .NET Core hasn't been called "Core" since .NET Core 3.1... .NET 5 and later are just ".NET".

Comment: When you installed the .NET 6.0 SDK and/or runtimes did you install only the x86 (32-bit) version? Via the [Download .NET 6.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) page make sure you're downloading and installing the x64 (64-bit) versions.

Comment: The out-of-memory issue is probably occurring because you're trying to move `byte[]` values around (the contents of `varbinary(max)` values to Azure blobs). The program needs to hold that entire `byte[]` value in memory and at some point the program can't get enough memory from the system to be able to do that. You could avoid that issue, even in 32-bit programs, by using a streaming methodology instead. Ref: [SqlClient Streaming Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: thanks for your info; I've worked on some of your suggestions and still testing. I will post the answer once I complete more testing. So far, I've uninstalled .net six, reinstalled X64, and changed how I pulled the blobs via your SQLClient Streaming Support link.